# How can I search in excel a bigger string than the cible string in the other table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search a string and get a corresponding status from an other table/sheet, but the string that I'm searching contain a bigger string than the targeted value.

### For example I have the strings in the first table that I'm looking for :

---

1. "Contract number is invalid : 000000786514 "
2. "Contract number 000000786514 is not attached"
3. "Contract number 000000786514 is Valid"

---

### and a corresponding table for the status :

---

Contract number is invalid | KO

Contract is not attached    | KO

Contract number is Valid   | OK

---

How can I add a column in the first table with the corresponding status ?, I tried VLOOKUP but it didn't work because the searched value is bigger than the cible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extract the part of the string you actually want to search for, this could be done with `LEFT()`

Comment: The issue with my data, is in some rows I have the number inside the String for example "Contract number 000000786514 is not attached" and "Contract number 000000786514 is Valid"

Comment: [This may be useful](https://www.howtoexcel.org/how-to-find-the-first-number-in-a-text-string/)